# Regex Search and Replace in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to do a Regex conditional search.

What I am looking to do is if there is Carriage Return (\r) followed by Upper and Lower Case alphabets the I want to add space ('') and remove carriage return but if after carriage there is anything else I just want to replace that. Is there a way I can do that using regex in Python

Sample Input:

> BCP-\rEngin\reerin\rg\rSyste\rms\rSupp\rort

Output:

> BCP- Engineering Systems Support

Data is in form of dataframe. I am currently using df.replace() function to replace "\r" with spaces (" ") but I would like it to be conditional.

Below is my code -

```py
df_replace = df.replace(to_replace=r"\r", value = " ", regex=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Comment: I have just basically tried replacing \r with nothing. But I am not sure how will I implement conditional replace.

Comment: What is an "uppercase character" for you? If the "ASCII" range A-Z is good enough for your case, that's easy, but if you want to handle *any* Unicode upper-case character, that's harder in standard Python regex.

Comment: Edit your question and show your attempt. It will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with python, but the regex you will need is as follows (perhaps someone with python experience can edit to customize this code):

**This will find all `\r` that precede an uppercase letter, so replace this with an empty string**:

```py
\\r(?![A-Z])
```

**This will find all `\r` that precede a lowercase letter, so replace this with a space**:

```py
\\r(?![a-z])
```

---

**EDIT**

Okay, here's one solution in Python I was able to put together for you:

```py
import re

myString = "BCP-\rEngin\reerin\rg\rSyste\rms\rSupp\rort"

myString = re.sub("\\r(?![A-Z])", "", myString)
myString = myString.replace("\r", " ")  # This can be simple string replace
```

Comment: will this work in dataframe -
`df_replace = df.replace(to_replace=r"\r", value = "@", regex=True)`

Can I replace your search condition here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution for this -

```
df_replace2 =  df.replace(to_replace = r"(\r)(?![A-Z])", value = "", regex=True)
df_replace3 = df_replace2.replace(to_replace = r"(\r)(?![a-z])", value = " ", regex=True)
```

Thanks @Brigadeiro for guiding with the solution